# Why didnt Prophet bring any new scientific discovery to enhance peoples life?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, allah, prophets

Why didn't Prophet bring any new scientific discovery, that would enhance peoples life and also show he had connection to a higher power that **knows** everything?
A new medical discovery, a new engineering discovery, etc? I find it very hard to grasp why this didnt happen?

Update :
I believe some prophets did this, for example David did, Also Solomon invested heavily in building constructions of any kind of massive proportions.
The point is, Islam engulfs all aspects of ones life, **literally** all aspects, and not only spirituality, and it always preaches about scientific symbols everywhere, and using ones brain to see God every where in everything. So its only logical, it brings some crafts in that regard.

Comment: Did any prophet before Muhammad bring any scientific discovery? A religion usually addresses the masses. Science is restricted on a minority.

Comment: I believe David did, Also Solomon invested heavily in building constructions of any kind of massive proportions. 
The point is, Islam engulfs all aspects of ones life, not spirituality, and it always preaches about scientific symbols everywhere, and using ones brain to see God every where in everything. So its only logical, it brings some crafts in that regard.

Comment: There's AFAIK no evidence in the Islamic sources supporting your claims about David and Solomon. Whether Islam encourages scientific research is rather subjective. And yes in Islam we are encouraged to worship Allah by knowledge and by using our mind.

Comment: There are many references in Quran for this. Noah created the arch which was an engineering feat of massive proportions. Also David created armor, Zolqarnain created a damn of massive size, and finally Solomon, who built arches and buildings among others : 
They worked for him as he desired, (making) arches, images, basons as large as reservoirs, and (cooking) cauldrons fixed (in their places): "Work ye, sons of David, with thanks! but few of My servants are grateful!" (Surah Saba, 13)
 We gave (in the past) knowledge to David and Solomon...(Surah An-Naml, 15)

Comment: And Solomon was David's heir. He said: "O ye people! We have been taught the speech of birds, and on us has been bestowed (a little) of all things: this is indeed Grace manifest (from Allah.)" (Surah An-Naml, 16), 
So there are many cases for sure.  
and I can give you lots and lots of saying concerning science as well.

Comment: None of these is about scientific discovery. And creation is something only Allah is able to.

Comment: my dear brother, they clearly show that! constructions, is not something rudimentary ! Do you think humans got to know everything by themselves? while God clearly says and indicates everything is from him? this really bugged me why not? why didnt a prophet of God that has all the knowledges in the worlds from God! cant even create a simplistic clock! or anything that benefit humanity?

Comment: First construction is not what I would call a scientific discovery so you should define your terms before asking in such a broad manner. Secondly prophets came with miracles that impressed their nation. As Arabs at the time reached a high level in eloquence and poetry the qur'an was the major miracle of Muhammed.

Comment: Again you failed at getting my point, probably because I failed at explaining it well. 
First of all, constructing something that massive, is an engineering feat! I say this because I am an engineer myself, its not like you nail couple of wood sticks and voila you've got yourself an aircraft carrier! 
Arabs weren't dummy idiots, they were intelligent, however, they were corrupt! by This I mean, they conquered the greatest empire on earth of the time so this shows they are intelligent. furthermore, we know Islam just engulfs all aspects of ones life.

Comment: So, the prophet could very easily advance humanity in all aspect, including science, as we as  muslims believe prophets had all the [earthly]knowledges. so if this belief is true, then why didnt they do anything? 
]

Comment: Muslims don't believe that prophets had all earthly knowledges at least not sunni Muslims! You have a wrong understanding of the Muslim belief. There are actually enough examples in both qur'an and sunnah refuting this statement.

Comment: can you name some?

Comment: You should move this to chat comments are not made for wide discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise that his bringing a new "craft" (invention) to the table proving connection to a higher power does not make logical sense because tons of people [past and modern history] are able to make new inventions; that would not be proof of his prophethood v. just over his genius at inventing something (like all other inventors). By itself, this premise has failed.

Connection to a higher is proven through doing something that NO other man can possibly do on his own [without God's aid]. This is why the Quraysh were asking for signs manifested through miracles because defying the natural laws of the world can only be done by someone who is supported by God.

- The Prophet (ﷺ) established through his miracles and prophecies that he had that connection with God. Miracles showed the power that Allah (ﷻ) supported him with and prophecies showed the foreknowledge that Allah (ﷻ) had given him.
- Qur'an gave lots of scientific knowledge that was ahead of its time and unknown to the Arabs (and everyone else).. yet another way showing people that the Qur'an is from a higher power with All Knowledge. To dismiss this and ask specifically for scientific knowledge that "enhances lives" is cherry picking the facts for reasons other than sincerity to truth.

As for enhancing lives, beyond the Prophet teaching people morals and manners that changed lives for the better, he did introduce medical remedies that cured people's physical illnesses which can be read through Ibn Al Qayyim Al Jawziyah's compilation book [The Prophetic Medicine](https://kalamullah.com/Books/Medicine.pdf) and other similar books. So while other Prophets [peace be upon them] were overseeing architecture, our Prophet (ﷺ) was overseeing people's health and medicinal cures.

That said, Allah (ﷻ) did not send Islam to the world to end disease, hunger, death, etc. These are trials that He intends to test people with. So that is partly why the "solution to everything" is not given. Rather, what is said is to bear with patience and make Dua. Dua is most beneficial.

In conclusion, Islam was at the forefront of science and medicine and already did everything you're asking for (establish connection to higher authority, enhance people's lives, bring new knowledge, etc) in far superior formats than what you are questioning for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is exactly what I was looking for. 
You had very good points in the beginning which really makes sense. What I wanted to know is that, Why couldnt we go forth with all power, in all directions? 
Islam did emphasize on learning and thinking and thats why we have golden age of Islamic civilization, but sadly it was 500 years after the prophet. 
I'd love to see my prophet have an active role in scientific discoveries, besides his spirituality. Your point concerning medcine was on point and I really enjoyed it. Do you have any more of these by any chance?

Comment: You're welcome. If I think of more, I'll let you know. The Prophet (ﷺ) was very involved in the Dunya matters as well as Akhirah matters.

Answer (score 1):

A few instances of science in Islam: 
The earth is like clouds, it moves, not static. The clouds, by very lattest finding, are flying lands with characterictic of machinery, there are roar and ramble sounds. 
The earth is like that too. It's a spacecraft with unimaginable speed.

The earth and sky were called by God to come to Him, either happily or feeling compeled.

(Universal Acceleration, in sya Allah, will fix the gravity based modern physics, and will totally replace gravity paradigm)

Qur'an doesn't give details, usually hints to figure out the evidences. It takes a serious research to obtain the clue and wonder of Quran.

Answer (score 1):

The question is problematic, in it implies that God's Prophets were sent to provide scientific discovery. If you look at any of the Prophets (Peace be upon them all) that was never their purpose. However, I am not a scholar, but if you look at the life of the Prophet (SAW), there are so many examples of his that modern science discovered much later. There is a book and video called "The Book of Signs" which is an excellent resource. There are many hadith that encourage us to learn and share and that is what scientific discovery (to do good) can be all about.